# Need to make bootable SD card from linux directories

Tags: linux, operating-system, bootable, mageia

I had SD card with linux that was working fine
I connected it to the pc and copied all directories there like root usr lib and so on ,,, I just have directories
I made a mistake and formatted the SD card and lost everything and it's not bootable

I am using linux mageia as os for both pc and SD

Please let me know how can I make the SD bootable using only the linux directories I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its impossible to have bootable image from these files. They can be used to restore the backup.